# mergesort: no errors and warnings when compile and link, but output is not in order

Tags: c, sorting

```
// msort.h
#ifndef _MSORT_H

void msort(int a[], int b[], int left, int right);

#endif //_MSORT_H


// msort.c
#include "msort.h"

void msort(int a[], int b[], int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        msort(a, b, left, (left + right) / 2);
        msort(a, b, (left + right) / 2 + 1, right);
        merge(a, b, left, right);
    }
}


// merge.h
#ifndef _MERGE_H_

void merge(int a[], int b[], int low, int high);

#endif //_MERGE_H_ 




// merge.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "merge.h"

void merge(int a[], int b[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid, begin1, end1, begin2, end2, k;

    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    begin1 = low;
    end1 = mid;
    begin2 = mid + 1;
    end2 = high;
    k = 0;

    while (begin1 <= end1 && begin2 <= end2)
    {
        if (a[begin1] <= a[begin2])
            b[k++] = a[begin1++];
        else
            b[k++] = a[begin2++];
    }

    while (begin1 <= end1)
        b[k++] = a[begin1++];

    while (begin2 <= end2)
        b[k++] = a[begin2++];
}





// test_merge.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "msort.h"
#include "merge.h"

#define N 10

int main()
{
    int *a, *b, i, left, right;

    left = 0;
    right = N - 1;

    a = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    if (a == NULL)
        exit(0);
    b = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    if (b == NULL)
        exit(0);

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    printf("array before sort:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 50;
        printf("%-5d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    msort(a, b, left, right);

    printf("array after sort:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%-5d", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;

}
```

Above are merge sort codes. msort.h and msort.c recursives until
 array is in right order. merge.h and merge.c merge two subarrays.
 test_merge.c is just a test for merge sort. No error and warning when
 compile and link.  But output is not in order, I couldn't find reason.

Can any one could give some help?

Comment: Why don't you sprinkle your code liberally with `printf` statements at sensible points to see what your algorithm is doing?

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should use the debugger to identify at what point the behaviour of the code diverges from what you expect, and then construct a [10-line test-case](http://sscce.org) based around that.

Comment: @attach, strangers took their to time to address you. Think about that before feeling sad your question was closed...

Comment: My guess is there is a off-by-one in the *split into two halves* part, but I am too lazy to do the math.

Comment: It would be helpful to state, in a comment before the function definitions, the pre- and post- conditions for `merge` and `msort`.

Answer (score 2):

You are never modifying the first array in either `msort` or `merge`, so the final call to `merge` in `msort` happily overwrites what has been done in the recursive calls to `msort`, hence the call

```
msort(a, b, left, right);
```

in `main` is equivalent to

```
merge(a, b, left, right);
```

In `merge`, you need to copy the merged chunks back into the array `a`, then the sorted array will at the end be in `a` (and also in `b`).

```
void merge(int a[], int b[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid, begin1, end1, begin2, end2, k;

    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    begin1 = low;
    end1 = mid;
    begin2 = mid + 1;
    end2 = high;
    k = 0;

    while (begin1 <= end1 && begin2 <= end2)
    {
        if (a[begin1] <= a[begin2])
            b[k++] = a[begin1++];
        else
            b[k++] = a[begin2++];
    }

    while (begin1 <= end1)
        b[k++] = a[begin1++];

    while (begin2 <= end2)
        b[k++] = a[begin2++];
    /* Now copy back into a */
    for(begin1 = low, begin2 = 0; begin1 <= high; ++begin1, ++begin2) {
        a[begin1] = b[begin2];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Dammit, these questions need to closed quickly before you come here with a good answer and I have to upvote you. Damn you +1